# gcc 4.7.2 virtual function bug

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw

There is a known bug in gcc 4.7.2 for MinGW that causes an invalid `this` pointer to be passed to a virtual function under some circumstances that involve virtual and non-virtual inheritance in the same class. The details are on [this Bugzilla page](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55171).

This bug has bitten me, and I need to fix it for a Qt application I am writing. There is a patch in the Bugzilla page, but how do I get a working version that incorporates this patch? As far as I can tell, the GNU download page only provides the original, buggy version. And the next version of gcc after 4.7.2 is 4.8.0, which I can't use because it will be incompatible with my Qt libraries.

Do I have to build gcc from the sources, after applying the patch? I certainly want to avoid that if I can!

Comment: An alternative to fixing the compiler might be to work around the bug in your code (e.g. by not using the combination of features that triggers the bug). Don't know if it's feasible in your case?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Even building gcc from source is a more attractive proposition than that :-/

Comment: Ouch. I hope you find an easy solution (FWIW, I remember building `gcc` a long time ago, and it was fairly painless).

Comment: Maybe it's better to fallback to GCC 4.7.1 and to rebuild Qt? From my point of view, this is the easiest what you can do. Rebuilding Qt or rebuilding GCC... do you care?

Comment: @Haroogan: You may be right. But if I go that way, I will try it first witg gcc 4.8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took Haroogan's advice (to rebuild Qt from source), but with GCC 4.8.0 instead of GCC 4.7.1. It worked! At least, I've been using it for three days now, and it hasn't thrown up any surprises yet. The only glitch was the intrinsic header files in GCC 4.8.0, which needed [this patch](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=29719&action=edit) applied to them. Other than that, it was plain sailing (i.e. it only took me two evenings).

**Updated to add:** I am now noticing some problems with the debugger. So perhaps I spoke too soon!